# laravel 5.5 - Undefined variable: products in @foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel-5, foreach

I'm facing some issues with a project build with Laravel 5.5.

I would like to save datas from a form in a database and display them in a array. I have code a `@foreach` loop in the `tbody` of the array's section:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Nom</th>
    <th>Prix</th>
    <th>Categorie</th>
    <th colspan="2">Action</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach($products as $product)
    <tr>
      <td>{{$product->id}}</td>
      <td>{{$product->name}}</td>
      <td>{{$product->price}}</td>
      <td>{{$product->category}}</td>
      <td><a href="{{action('ProductController@edit', $product->id)}}" 
         class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a></td>
      <td>
      <form action="{{action('ProductController@destroy', $product->id)}}" 
         method="post">
         {{csrf_field()}}
         <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
         <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
      </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Form**

```
<form id ="AddFormProduct" method="post" action="{{url('products')}}">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Nom:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="price">Prix:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="price">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="category">Categorie:</label>
                <select name="selectCategory" id="selectCategory" class="form-control">
                    @foreach($categories as $category)
                        <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-left:38px">Enregistrer</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

First problem is that I cannot display the view (with the array & the form) because I have this:

> ErrorException (E_ERROR)
>   Undefined variable: products (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Laratest\resources\views\template.blade.php)

I've tried many solutions, the last one is:

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Product;
use View;

class ProductController extends Controller
{

public function index()
{
    $products = Product::orderBy('id','name')->get();
    return view('template', compact('products','categories'));

    // $products = Product::all();
    // return view('template', ['products' => $products]);
}


public function create()
{
   //
}


public function store(Request $request)
{
      $product = $this->validate(request(), [
        'name' => 'required',
        'price' => 'required|numeric',
        'category' => 'required'
      ]);
      Product::create($product);
      return back()->with('success', 'Le produit a bien été ajouté !');
}

public function edit($id)
{
    $product = Product::find($id);
    return view('products.edit',compact('product','id'));
}

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $product = Product::find($id);
    $this->validate(request(), [
      'name' => 'required',
      'price' => 'required|numeric',
      'category' => 'required'
    ]);
    $product->name = $request->get('name');
    $product->price = $request->get('price');
    $product->category = $request->get('category');
    $product->save();
    return redirect('products')->with('success','Le produit a bien été 
modifié !');
}

public function destroy($id)
{
    $product = Product::find($id);
    $product->delete();
    return redirect('products')->with('success','Le produit a bien été 
supprimé !');
}
}
```

**Model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class Product extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 
        'price', 
        'category'
    ];
}
```

**Routes**

```
Route::resource('products','ProductController');
Route::get('/monCommerce', 'ProductController@index')->name('products');
```

The second problem is that I don't know how to get my values from a `select>options`, it's only works with input fields. = **RESOLVED**

Please suggest.

Comment: This solution is not work? `return view('template', ['products' => $products]);`

Comment: try -- return view('template', compact(['products','categories']));

Comment: For your second question try changing

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers but it doesn't work either...

Answer (score 0):

**For your first question change your route to**

```
Route::get('/monCommerce', 'ProductController@index')->name('products');
Route::resource('products','ProductController');
```

If that is not the case then : 
It may be because you have an empty table or table without any rows this will definitely return a null object. So check for that error. You can either do this on your controller or on blade itself, I recommend doing it on your controller.

If checking it on blade :

try doing the follow:

```
@if($products == null || $products == "")
  No data found
@else
  Your foreach loop
@endif
```

If trying out on controller:
Just use try and catch exception handler.

**For your second question try changing**

```
<select name="selectCategory" id="selectCategory" class="form-control">
```

to

```
   <select name="category" id="selectCategory" class="form-control">
```

Because you have category field and you have specified category as fillable in your model. If you would like to keep your select name as selectCategory then you will have to change request in your controller.

Just in case if you want to keep selectCategory name in your select form

In your ProductController@store

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   $request->category=$request->selectCategory;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Deepesh Thapa, It's works for my second question. My datas are stored in my db. I've change the name of my select

Comment: For my principal issue, I already have some datas in my table "products". I've tried your @if condition but it returns the same error (Undefined variable: products)

Comment: Are you sure you have returned projects in your controller

Comment: Could you check where exactly it is returning the undefined variable. On your log file you should see a line where it is throwing an error. Just go to the file on Storage>framework>views   Find the view file for template.blade.php and find the line. let me know exactly where he error persists

Comment: Just after the tbody tag, at the beginning of the foreach (see at [link](https://ibb.co/dpo4Ny))

Comment: please use dd($products) and check whether it returns the products object with list of items after you fetch the Product model in function index.